# Use Maven for dependencies together with GWT Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

So far I'm not using maven for a `GWT` project. When I deploy it to the `GAE` Google App Engine, I just have to right click > Google > Deploy to App Engine. Then the `war` folder is generated automatically and everything runs fine.

If I change the project to `maven` structure, the menu point in `project settings > Google > Web Application` tells me: `Launch and deploy from this directory (disabled because Maven)`.

As a result, when deploying, the war folder is not generated/updated!

So: how can I use maven for dependency management, and still use the GWT/GAE `Eclipse Plugin` to deploy and start my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to go through this introductory exercise in maven : http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

What you are describing is possible, but takes some work and understanding of maven to accomplish.  If you would like to convert your project to maven, it might take a bit more work than just changing the project to the maven structure in eclipse.  An example maven project for App Engine is here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-java .  Some App Engine specific docs on maven are here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven